# Java sort string both alphabetically and keep ASCII order

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

The list is: `Arrays.asList("Za", "ab", "AB", "Sa", "1ab", "Ab", "!Ab");`

If I use `stream().sorted()` then the order is: `!Ab 1ab AB Ab Za ab` --> Za should not be in front of ab.

If I use `sorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` then the order is `!Ab 1ab ab AB Ab Za` --> This time, AB is behind ab.

Is there any way to combine the two rules so we have list sorted alphabetically and uppercase is greater than lower case?

---

**Added Example**: `1AB - A0B - AbD - aBD - abd1 - ZAB`
Sorted alphabetically (Z is  never in front of a) and Number >  Uppercase > Lowercase (`AbD > aBD`)

Comment: Yes, by creating your own `Comparator`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `ab` and `AB` are equal; hence themselves are unordered in the result.
So add a normal comparison, as capitals come before small letters.

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
            .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

---

***After comment***

```
list.stream()
    .sorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
            .thenComparing(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
```

Comment: I notice that this will fail the order with the following test case `aB, a0B, AoB, 0AB, ab2` -- this time `AoB` is behind `aB`. Is there any way rather than comparing each character of two strings in custom `Comparator`?

Comment: I have added a version with reverse order. Not entirely sure that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Joop but `reverseOrder()` will put  `AoB` behind `ab2`. I created a custom Comparator, put two strings in two arrays of character and then compare each character using `Character.codePointAt()`. I don't think there is an out of the box java api for this kind of order, which is popular though.

Answer (score 2):

Write a comparator class like this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int result = o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        if(result==0)
            result = o1.compareTo(o2);
        return result;
    }

}
```

And then where you call the sort function, pass an object of the comparator:

```
stream().sorted(new CustomComparator());
```

Comment: If you want to reverse the case sorting, i.e., have `a` before `A`, just reverse the second comparison like so:
`if(result==0) result = o2.compareTo(o1);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to achieve this in Java7

```
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Za", "ab", "AB", "Sa", "1ab", "Ab", "!Ab");

  Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
      int compare = o1.toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toLowerCase());
            if(compare==0)
                compare = o1.compareTo(o2);
            return compare;
      }

  };

 Collections.sort(list,comparator);
 System.out.println(list);
```

In Java8 use this code

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Za", "ab", "AB", "Sa", "1ab", "Ab", "!Ab");

Stream<String> stream = list.stream()
                             .sorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
                                  .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));

stream.forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));
```